# How is Jersey framework implement JAX-RS API in REST?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I know there are a lot of answers on this questions , but i am still confused about difference between JAX-RS API(the specification), and Jersey framework( reference implementation).

I read that:

Jersey framework basically uses com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer servlet to intercept all the incoming requests. As we configure in our projects web.xml, that all the incoming rest request should be handled by that servlet. There is an init-param that is configured with the jersey servlet to find your REST service classes. REST service classes are not Servlet and they need NOT to extend the HttpServlet as you did in your code. These REST service classes are simple POJOs annotated to tell the jersey framework about different properties such as path, consumes, produces etc. When you return from your service method, jersey takes care of marshalling those objects in the defined 'PRODUCES' responseType and write it on the client stream

My question is when you say :" jersey takes care of marshalling those objects in the defined 'PRODUCES' responseType and write it on the client stream",  what you mean by jersey , what is actual class or library  that handles objects .

I am confused when i read that jersey is the engine that handles JAX-RS API specification. Can someone please explain what exactly is behind word jersey in this sentence? What actual class from Jersey do do the job of processing requests and responses in Jersey?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The concept of specification and implementation is really pretty basic software engineering concepts. Your specification is the high level design. To help understand, I just came up with a really simple example.

Say I want to have a parsing library. I know how I want to be able to use it. The only problem is that I am not very good at writing parsing code. So I create a high level specification, and I outsource the implementation. Here are the three classes that are part of the spec. They are all contained in one "API jar", say **myparsers-api.jar**

```
public interface Parser {
    String[] parse(String s);
}

public interface ParserFactory {
    Parser getBySpaceParser();
    Parser getByCommaParser();
}

public class ParserDepot {
    private static ServiceLoader<ParserFactory> loader
            = ServiceLoader.load(ParserFactory.class);

    public static ParserFactory getDefaultParserFactory() {
        final List<ParserFactory> factories = new ArrayList<>();
        loader.forEach(factories::add);
        if (factories.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No ParserFactory found");
        }
        return factories.get(0);
    }
}
```

So at this point, I can actually *code* against this jar. If I were to uses it as is right now in another project, the project would compile just fine.

```
ParserFactory factory = ParserDepot.getDefaultParserFactory();
Parser parser = factory.getBySpaceParser();
String[] tokens = parser.parse("Hello World");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
```

So even though there is no *implementation* of this specification, I can still code against it, and compile against it. But when I try to actually run the program, it won't work, as there is no implementation. You can try to run this code, and you will get an `IllegalStateException` (see [the docs for ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) if you're unfamiliar with this pattern).

So I outsource the implementation to say a company called Stack Overflow. They get my myparsers-api.jar and they need to give me back an implementation. They would need to implement a `ParserFactory`, and a couple of `Parser`s. They might look something like this

```
public class SoByCommaParser implements Parser {
    @Override
    public String[] parse(String s) {
        return s.split("\\s+,\\s+");
    }
}

public class SoBySpaceParser implements Parser {
    @Override
    public String[] parse(String s) {
        return s.split("\\s+");
    }
}

public class SoParserFactory implements ParserFactory {
    @Override
    public Parser getBySpaceParser() {
        return new SoBySpaceParser();
    }

    @Override
    public Parser getByCommaParser() {
        return new SoByCommaParser();
    }
}
```

Now Stack Overflow gives me back a jar (say **so-myparsers-impl.jar**) with these three classes and the required META-INF/services file (per the ServiceLoader pattern), and now when I add the so-myparsers-impl.jar to my project and try to run it again, the program now works, because now it has an *implementation*.

This is exactly how the JAX-RS spec works. It only defines the high level design of how it *should* work. The classes, interfaces, and annotations that are part of that design are placed in an "API jar" just like my high level parsers are put into a jar. Implementations cannot alter these classes. All the classes that are part of the JAX-RS specification (version 2.x) are put into one single jar [`javax.ws.rs-api`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0). You can code against that jar, and your code will compile just fine. But there is nothing to make it "work".

You check out both [the written specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr339/index.html) and the [classes defined by the specification](https://github.com/jax-rs/api/tree/master/jaxrs-api/src/main/java/javax/ws/rs) and you will notice that the only classes included in the source code are those mentioned in the specification. But what you should notice is that the written specification doesn't mention anything at all about how it is supposed to be implementation.  Take for example the following code

```
@Path("/test")
public class TestResource {
    @GET
    public String get() {
        return "Testing";
    }
}

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        classes.add(TestResource.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

Now the specification states that this is all we need to run a JAX-RS application in a servlet container. And that's all it says. It says nothing about how it all supposed to work. This is just how it is *designed* to work.

So what, is there some magic voodoo in Java that we don't know about that will make this `Application` class start a server, and some hocus pocus that will make a `@Path` annotated class automatically accept requests. No. Some body needs to provide the *engine*. The engine might be 20,000 lines of code just to make the above code work as specified.

That being said, Jersey is just the name of an implementation. It's like when I outsourced my parser implementation to Stack Overflow; The name Jersey itself is just the name of the project, just like Hadoop is a name of the project. In this case, what the project is, is an implementation of the JAX-RS specification. And because JAX-RS is just a specification, it means that *anyone* can implement it. If you wanted to, you could write your own implementation. As long as it works how it is defined to work in the written specification, then you can say that your code is an implementation of JAX-RS. There's more than just Jersey out there; you also have [RESTEasy](http://resteasy.jboss.org/), which is another implementation.

As far as *how* Jersey implements the engine, that is way too broad. What I can do, is give you a high level overview of what happens behinds the scenes.

A JAX-RS application is defined to run inside of a servlet container. If you understand servlet containers and the servlet spec, then you'll know that the only way to handle requests is either by writing a `HttpServlet` or `Filter`. So if you want to implement JAX-RS then you need to able to handle requests either through a `HttpServlet` or a `Filter`. The [`ServletContainer`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.26-b07/containers/jersey-servlet-core/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletContainer.java) you mentioned, is actually both. So for Jersey, this is the "entry point" into the Jersey application, as far as request processing is concerned. It can be configured in a number of ways (I've leave that research to you).

And if you understand how to write your own servlet, then you know all you get is an `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse`. You need to figure out what to do from there; get request info from the request, and send response info back out in the response. Jersey handles all of this.

If you really want to get into the gory details of what is going on under the hood, you will just need to to dig into the source code, starting from the entry point, the `ServletContainer`. Be prepared to spend months on this to get a really good understanding of how it all works. It's not something that can be explained in one Stack Overflow post, if that's what you're expecting.

Comment: This is the best answer ever! Ty so much mate. Now i  just need to study it.:)

Answer (score 1):

You already pointed that JAX-RS is a **specification** and Jersey is the **implementation** which is how is Java especially Java EE work, maybe this [article](https://pedanticdevs.com/2017/06/java-ee-fundamentals-what-is-java-ee.html) can explain more better.

To summarize JAX-RS is just a specification, there is no real implementation. The real implementation was done by Jersey and other library that following JAX-RS specification.

Comment: How jersey actually implement , can you please explain work flow? What classes are involved in actual implementation beside ServletContainer who handles the requests?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not confident to explain how jersey actually implemented. Because mostly the one that implement Jersey was Application Server such as Glassfish, Wildfly, etc. But if you want, you can see the full document about JAX-RS on [here](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=339). It does have full explanation about JAX-RS and how to implement it which is you maybe can understand how Jersey work.

Comment: Ok, but can you explain what is workflow when Application server implement  some specification?